# Turn off windows 8 update to 8.1 and delete downloaded update

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, updates, automatic-update

Is there any possibility to turn off windows 8 update to windows 8.1? First it was asking me all the time if I want to update it, I pressed deny, now it changed the strategy and it automatically downloaded the update and after installation, it will update my system from windows 8 to windows 8.1, which I really don't want to. I don't need to have pc full of bugs. Is there possibility remove this update before installation and deny it at all to prevent it in feature?

Comment: I can guarantee you that upgrading to `Windows 8.1` would make your system less buggy then currently is.

Comment: ignore the update kb3008273 in WindowsUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Under `Control Panel` you will find at the bottom `Windows Update`.  There you will see a status of what can be updated.  At your left you'll see a `Change Settings` link in Blue.  At this point you will select `Check for updates but let me choose whether to download them`.  Contrary to popular Belief this is the safest setting due to M$ inability to properly write updates that are not malicious to everyday use.  Select `Ok` to apply your settings.